# Does typecasting have no effect in statement 1 in the below Code?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p;
    p = arr;
    p = (char*)((int*)(p));
    printf("%d, ", *p);
    p = (int*)(p+1); //............statement 1
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `p = (int*)(p+1);` means character pointer is type cast to integer pointer. So when we dereference `p`, It fetches the contents up to next `int` size (2 bytes or 4 bytes, depending on compiler). But when I am solving this question at www.indiabix.com, they have given

> answer: 2, 0

How it can be `2, 0`? As per my analysis,the answer should be `2, 3`. Can anyone explain what should be the correct answer and why?

Comment: http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/pointers/discussion-243

Comment: http://ideone.com/HfOj0Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say an `int` takes four bytes.

In a little endian system, the memory layout of `arr` looks like:

```
|   | <--- one byte
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In a big endian system, the memory layout of `arr` looks like:

```
|   | <--- one byte
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In a little endian system,

```
*p = 2;
*(p+1) = 0;
```

In a big endian system,

```
*p = 0;
*(p+1) = 0;
```

Depending on your platform, the output will be:

```
2 0
```

or

```
0 0
```

The code you have is perhaps meant to confuse. The line

```
p = (char*)((int*)(p));
```

doesn't do a damn thing.

The line

```
p = (int*)(p+1);
```

has the same effect as:

```
p = p+1;
```

Comment: p = (int*)(p+1); means p is now an integer pointer then it has to read  0 0 0 3 i.e., 4 bytes. So output should be 2, 3

Comment: @JhansiRani, Had you used `p = ((int*)p + 1)`, then `*p` will be `3`.

Comment: Now, is it mean p is not changed to integer pointer when we write p = (int*)(p+1); I am getting confused because, we are type casting and then assigning p itself. I know that type cast means temporary.

Comment: When you do `p = (int *)(p+1);`, _first_ you're adding `p+1`. This adds one to a `char *` pointer, so the new pointer is pointing at the second char, not the second int. Then the `(int *)` cast happens, then the result is assigned back to `p`. However, `p` has been declared as a `char *` pointer variable, so assigning any value to `p` implicitly converts that value to a `char *`.